# Parse htm as php7 in Plesk and Ubuntu

Tags: plesk, php-7

I'm new to Plesk. I use 12.5.30 on Ubuntu 14.04 (1205160201.11).

In php settings I've selected PHP 7.0.4 running as FPM application served by Apache. When I look at the phpinfo() file I see that PHP Version 7.0.4 is used. I want to also parse my .htm pages with PHP 7.0.4. I added the following line to my .htaccess:

```
AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm
```

When I parse a .htm file with phpinfo() I see that PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 is used.

How can I use 7.0.4 with .htm files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to switch PHP handler to PHP 7 on domain

and (for Apache+FastCGI handler type) add in .htaccess or "Additional Apache directives":

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <Files ~ (\.htm$)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .htm
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

in case of Apache+PHP-FPM handler type:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
    <Files ~ (\.htm$)>
        SetHandler proxy:unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/<YOUR DOMAIN NAME HERE>/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

As PHP-FPM handles only .php extension you have to specify in `/var/www/vhosts/system/<YOU DOMAIN NAME HERE>/conf/php.ini` (after editing this file you need to trigger PHP-FPM pool rebuilding, e.g. change some minor PHP settings):

```
[php-fpm-pool-settings]
security.limit_extensions = .php .htm
```

Change PHP handler you can on "PHP settings" page:

[image: plesk switch php version on domain]

If you have not see PHP 7 in dropdown list it may mean that PHP 7 handler is not installed, you may install it via command line plesk installer or via UI at server's settings:

[image: plesk install PHP 7]

It's starts plesk installer and open it's web UI where you can "Add componens" install PHP 7 handler:

[image: plesk PHP 7 handlers]

Comment: Thansk @oleg. I've installed and selected PHP 7.0.4 in 'Websites & domains'. When I use the .php extension PHP 7.0.4 is used. But when I use a .htm extension PHP 5.5.9 Ubuntu is used. I think it has something to do with my .htaccess which is 

`AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm`

I give your answer a vote, for the outstanding way of explaining how to install a new php version in Plesk.

Comment: @MartijnJSS indeed there some pitfalls, I've updated the answer.